# Passing string literal to function taking 'char *' and getting a compiler warning

Tags: c++

Just a syntax question, here is my code snippet. (Sorry, browser isn't letting me paste properly into stack overflow.)

```
#include <iostream>     /* 'iostream.h' is deprecated. */
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;    /* Required. */

FILE *OpenFile(char *Filename)
{
        FILE *FP;

        if((FP = fopen(Filename, "r")) == NULL)
        {       /* Error opening file. */
                std::cout << "[!!] Unable to open database!"
                          << " Are you sure it exists?\n"
                          << "[<<] Database Unchanged.\n";
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     /* End program. */
        }

        else    /* Properly opened the file. */
                return FP;
}

int main(void)
{
        FILE *Data;     /* Our database file pointer. */
        Data = OpenFile("Data.txt");
        printf("Success!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I get the following warning:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:27:28: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
$
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please paste your code here.  Don't make us visit an external site to see your code.

Comment: I know, firefox has been acting weird for me, trying to figure out why.

Comment: Report errors on `cerr`; that's what it is designed for.  And, in theory, it would be a good idea to use `FILE *Data = OpenFile("data.txt");` and to close the file before exiting.  In practice, in this context, it does not matter much, but in many contexts, not freeing allocated resources is a bad idea, and RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) suggests the initialize on definition notation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

String literals in C++ are of type “array of *n* `const char`” (where *n* is the number of characters in the string, including the terminating NUL).  Declare your function this way:

```
FILE *OpenFile(const char *Filename)
```